# Is $f(x)$ reducible if $f(a)=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, proof-verification

I am confused about this seemingly trivial question:

> If $f(a) = 0$ for some $a\in D$, then when is $f(x)$ reducible in $D[x]$? ($D$ is an integral domain).

My answer: Always.

Let $f(a)=0$. Then $f(x)$ has $(x-a)$ as factor. So $f(x)$ can be written as $f(x) = (x-a)h(x)$. Now what is the guarantee that $h(x)\in D[x]$? I believe it is the division algorithm for polynomials (remainder = 0). Am I correct in proving $h(x)\in D[x]$?

Comment: Yes, that follows by the Division Algorithm. You also need that $\,h\neq 0\,$ is a nonunit, or that $\,\deg h > 1,\,$ depending on your definition of "reducible".

Comment: @BillDubuque yes I need $h\neq0$ should be a non-unit. I have not proved that.

Comment: But using deg f = deg (x-a) + deg h, we can get deg $h \geq1$ for deg $f\geq2$ and the case deg f=1 is trivial, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you've got the right idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Always" is wrong. For example $f(x)=x-a$ is irreducible.